# External JavaScript accessing html elements and assigning to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am starting out using JavaScript and I cannot understand why I cannot assign a HTML attribute description to a variable in an external JavaScript function. It works ok when inside the HTML page but will not work in the external script as the variable I am assigning tests out as undefined.

```
function NewFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("Year").href;
  //var x="hello"
  if (x === undefined) {
      alert("x is undefined");
  } else {
      alert("x is defined");
  }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

I can change demo if I use the var x="hello".  However if I try to assign 
x the document.getElementById("Year").href it reports back as undefined. This code works well inside the source page as a local script.

I am missing something as it seems you cannot assign a variable, information read from the HTML page.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: It should work fine, can you set up a JSfiddle or show your relevant HTML and full JS?

Comment: Must apologize to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely problem in the time moment when script is loaded. Just call your function when DOM is ready ( see event [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for more info).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  NewFunction()
});
```

Below is your code ( with func calling on DOM Ready ) and everything seems to work fine. Try to compare with our actual code.

```js
function NewFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Year").href;
  //var x="hello"
  if (x === undefined) {
      alert("x is undefined");
  } else {
      alert("x is defined");
  }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  NewFunction()
});
```

```html
<a href='123' id='Year'>123</a>

<p id='demo'>123</p>
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Yes it works well when it is embedded into the HTML page. But I am calling it from an external JavaScript file which is activated on a button click once the page has loaded. I must not be able to assign HTML elements in  external js code but I am able to modify the page via the code which is what I don't understand.

Comment: Must apologize to all. Rechecked my HTML code and did not realize that the element I was referencing did not have a href in the element as I was looking at the next item. The item I was actually referencing had a src instead and once I change it to                                                             var x =document.getElementById("Year").src; the code did what it was supposed to do. My apologies and thanks for the help I learnt a lot and i will be more careful in my posts

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `<script>` tag to the end of the body, or execute you function in `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is probably running **before** your DOM (html page) is loaded. You need to wrap your code around a `onload` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Year").href;
  //var x="hello"
  if (x === undefined) {
      alert("x is undefined");
  } else {
      alert("x is defined");
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
};
```

Comment: I call the function via a button on the web page after the page has loaded.

Comment: Can you show us your html code?